# Need to display list view items with custom alignment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am trying to display the listview group items as like in the attached screenshot, but still i have facing   issue while displaying group view items

Requirement:

Group header needs to display in horizontal alignment and corresponding group items are needs to be aligned in vertical alignment

[image: Screenshot]

```
 <ListView
        x:Name="listview"
        BorderThickness="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
       
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        


        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                            Padding="5,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="14"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Please suggestion a solution to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the orientation you would have to set the `GroupStyle.Panel`. Because of your requirement to arrange the items multiline you should use a `WrapPanel`.

To make it behave properly you should disable the horizontal `ScrollViewer` of the `ListView` (to allow the items to wrap) and give the `ListView` a fixed height (in order to make the vertical `ScrollViewer` visible).

Since you don't modify the layout of the `GroupItem` and the `ListView` you can safely remove the `GroupStyle.ContainerStyle` (at least the `Controltemplate` override) and the `ListView.ItemsPanel` template override. In fact setting `ItemsPanelTemplate` of a `ListBox` or `ListView` explicitly to `StackPanel` or generally to something other than a `VirtualizingPanel` removes the ability to virtualize items. UI virtualization significantly improves performance, so you don't want to disable it.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" 
          Height="400"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.Panel>
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock
            Padding="5,0,0,0"
            FontSize="14"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can get multi line items as per requirement , only group header text is visible, group items binding is not working  Please check screenshot.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong? The group items  are visible in your screenshot. Did I misunderstood your point?

Answer (score 1):

You should define the Panel property for GroupStyle and you can remove the ItemsPanel for the ListView:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

Complete code for setting the groups for anyone interested:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key='cvs' 
                  Source="{Binding Path=Products}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ProductType" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView
    x:Name="listview"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                        Padding="5,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="14"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Regarding the model used: I set up a simple ProductCvs class

```
public class ProductCvs
{
    public string Product { get; set; }

    public string ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it working fine required alignment but still i need to display  two rows with corresponding columns, each column should contain two groups like  screenshot attached recently in description

Comment: I don't think you can achive that directly with a ListView. I believe you would need a second ListView to make the second "Row". Or you could add other columns and change the Orientation back to Vertical. But you will have to prepare the Data to be in the different columns. That seems a bit hackish